# Why isn't the related_name working for models?

Tags: django

There are question and answer tables related to each other. Each question has one answer. I need to check the answer field in the CompanyGeneralInfoAnswers model.

```
class CompanyGeneralInfoQuestion(models.Model):
    rfi = models.ForeignKey(Rfis, models.DO_NOTHING)
    question = models.CharField(max_length=512)

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'company_info__questions'


class CompanyGeneralInfoAnswers(models.Model):
    question = models.OneToOneField('CompanyGeneralInfoQuestion', models.DO_NOTHING, related_name='answer_to_question')
    answer = models.CharField(max_length=4096, blank=True, null=True)
    class Meta:
        db_table = 'company_info_answers'
```

To do this, I make this request.

```
round = kwargs.get('rfiid')
exist_company_question = CompanyGeneralInfoQuestion.objects.filter(rfi=round)
if exist_company_question:
    for q in exist_company_question:
        print(q.answer_to_question.answer)
```

But got an error

```
RelatedObjectDoesNotExist: CompanyGeneralInfoQuestion has no answer_to_question.
```

Comment: A `OneToOne` means that every `CompanyGenerialInfoAnswers` points to a *unique* question, not that each question *has* an answer. THis one apparently does not.

Comment: change OneToOne to ManyToMany

Comment: @Tushortz I don't think this connection ManyToManyField is appropriate here. rather Foreignkey?

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem I try with  Foreignkey but got `AttributeError: 'RelatedManager' object has no attribute 'answer'`

Comment: I seem to have found a solution. Using `Foreignkey` and query `q.answer_to_question.get().answer`

Comment: yes @Jekson you are right. i didn't look at that properly